# Recurrence sequences with two initial condition: how do I calculate the limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I've done some exercises with recurrence sequences with one initial condition. So, now that I'm attempting one exercise with two initial conditions I'm confused. Could you show me what to do?

Let $x_0 = \alpha >0$ and $x_1 = \beta >0$. How do I calculate the limits of the following two sequences?

$$x_{n+2} = \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$$

and

$$x_{n+2} = \sqrt{x_{n+1}^2 + x_n ^2}$$

Comment: Hint: You still have ONE condition in this example..

Comment: @JDrinas How so?

Comment: You wish to relate $x_{n+1}$ with $x_n$..It's right there..$a=b,c=b,$ therefore $a=c$..:-)

Comment: Also,all the terms of the sequence are positive.

Comment: Ahh,I think I made a mistake..Sorry for that-I thought it was one sequence..Really sorry..

Answer (score 1):

The second sequence diverges. If the limit would be $a$, we would get

$a=\sqrt{a^2+a^2}=a\sqrt{2}$, which is a contradicition (unless $a=0$).

The sequence is increasing because of $x_{n+2}>x_{n+1}$ for all $n\ge 0$.

So, it is not oscillating and the limit cannot be $0$ because of $x_1,x_2>0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Could you show me some more details about the first one (including the calculation of limit inferior and limit superior)?

Comment: And, in general, could you tell me how I should approach this kind of sequences with two or more initial conditions?

Comment: The entries in the first sequence are $a$,$b$,$\frac{b}{a}$,$\frac{1}{a}$,$\frac{1}{b}$,$\frac{a}{b}$,$a$,$b$, ...

Comment: And then how do I compute limit superior and inferior?

Comment: This depends on the values $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first sequence, there is no limit. The sequence is periodic with $x_6=x_0$ which is straightforward to see if you start substituting in the values.

Likewise the second sequence has no limit. The general term is of the form $p\alpha^2 +q\beta^2$, where $p$ and $q$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: The first has no limit **unless** $\alpha=\beta=1$, in which case every term is $1$.

Comment: The second sequence should have limit $+\infty$. Also, for the first one, I have two questions: 1. how do you realize that it is periodic without calculating 6 values? 2. could you show me how to calculate limit superior and limit inferior of this sequence?

Comment: I calculated the values, which was easy enough. I didn't know beforehand it was periodic. I should add the condition that $a\neq b\neq1$ as suggested above.